# Android project with ORMLite fails to build in ant

Tags: android, ant, ormlite

I have an Android project with the ORMLite library, which I would like to publish on F-Droid. The project compiles without a problem in Eclipse. However, F-Droid uses ant to build the project, and on their side, the project fails to build with errors in the (summarized) code below:

```
private Dao<Habit, Integer> habitDao;
private Dao<Day, Integer> dayDao;

public Dao<Habit, Integer> getHabitDao() throws SQLException {
    if (habitDao == null) {
        habitDao = getDao(Habit.class);
    }
    return habitDao;
}

public Dao<Day, Integer> getDayDao() throws SQLException {
    if (dayDao == null) {
        dayDao = getDao(Day.class);
    }
    return dayDao;
}
```

The error is on the habitDao = getDao(Habit.class) and dayDao = getDao(Day.class) lines, with the following error message:

```
type parameters of D cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable D with upper bounds com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao,com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao
```

This is the same issue as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ormlite-android/rUVI0d-khKk, and is supposedly a bug in the Java compiler.

Now, I am not an expert developer, so what adding explicit casts means is not intuitive to me. Here is how I altered my code:

```
public Dao<Habit, Integer> getHabitDao() throws SQLException {
    if (habitDao == null) {
        habitDao = getDao(Habit.class);
    }
    return (Dao<Habit, Integer>)habitDao;
}

public Dao<Day, Integer> getDayDao() throws SQLException {
    if (dayDao == null) {
        dayDao = getDao(Day.class);
    }
    return (Dao<Day, Integer>)dayDao;
}
```

This fixed the problem for me, ant successfully built the project on my end, and the app works without a hitch. However, F-Droid's ant build process still failed with the same error as above. Now I am lost, because I can no longer "debug" this on my end, as far as my ant is concerned, there is no issue with the project, and therefore any change I make is pure guesswork.

I tried one more thing after that:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Dao<Habit, Integer> getHabitDao() throws SQLException {
    if (habitDao == null) {
        habitDao = (Dao<Habit, Integer>)getDao(Habit.class);
    }
    return (Dao<Habit, Integer>)habitDao;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Dao<Day, Integer> getDayDao() throws SQLException {
    if (dayDao == null) {
        dayDao = (Dao<Day, Integer>)getDao(Day.class);
    }
    return (Dao<Day, Integer>)dayDao;
}
```

But this is pure guessing, and on F-Droid's side, the build process still fails with the same error.

Any advice on how to fix this will be much appreciated.

Edit: The app is open source, so anyone willing to try and build it on their own with ant is welcome to: https://github.com/blaztriglav/did-i

Comment: Cloned your repository. Called ant release and it works fine

Comment: Eugen, thanks for trying it out. Several apps on F-Droid have started having this issue, so it might be something on their end.